# Как исправить ошибку Anaconda

Tags: python, install, anaconda, directory

Не знаю какую директорию использовать чтобы оно установилось. Все перепробовала. Без пробелов и знаков кириллицы, не помогает. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй создай папку и при выборе местоположения файла укажи эту папку.
Главное, чтобы она пуста была. Эта проблема очень часто возникает